# Insert a List collection into a Map Collection with the same index

Tags: apex, list, map

I am trying to add a List of collection to a Map Collection with the same Index.

I have this Code:

```
List<Account> accountContactList = [SELECT Id,Name FROM Account];
Map<Integer,List<Account>> objWrapper = new Map<Integer,List<Account>>();
List<Account> listToMapCOllection = new List<Account>();
Integer viewPerPage = 5;
Integer counterIndex = 1;
Integer counterToViewPerPage  = 1;

        for(Account accCont: accountContactList){
            if(counterToViewPerPage <= viewPerPage){
                listToMapCOllection.add(accCont);
                counterToViewPerPage++;
            }else{
                objWrapper.put(counterIndex,listToMapCOllection);
                counterIndex++;
                counterToViewPerPage = 1;
                listToMapCOllection.clear();
            }
        }
```

Now my problem is when the result of accountContactList  Collection is only 2 or the size of the collection is an ODD, the code will nerver go to else condition and it will not add to my Map Collection (objWrapper ). 
Any help please.

EDITED:
In every loop of 5 the list of collection will add to the Map collection, So for the first 5 of loop of the list of the collection will add to map with the index of 1 and the second loop of five will add to Map with the index of 2.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep this approach intact and make a minimal, simple change, add a condition *after* your loop to see if you have any elements in the collection.

```
for (Account record : collection)
{
    // current logic
}
if (!listToMapCollection.isEmpty())
{
    // add to map
}
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that in every loop of 5 the list of collection will add to the Map collection, So for the first 5 of loop of the list of the collection will add to map with the index of 1 and the second loop of five will add to Map with the index of 2.

Comment: Yeah you would just use the `map.size()` as the key for your `put` call.